# Determining the polar form for all n-th roots of unity.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

By definition $ z \in\mathbb{C}$ is a n-th root of unity iff $z^n = 1$. My assignment is to

> (iv) List all n-th roots of unity in their polar form. You may use that there are only $n$ Elements with z $\in\mathbb{C}$ so that $z^n = 1$.

What I started out with is this:

$ z^n = 1 = 1 + 0i = 1(cos(0 + 2\pi k) + i \ sin(0+2\pi k))$ for $k \in\mathbb{Z}$.

$z = 1^{1/n} (cos(2\pi k) + i \ sin(2\pi k))^{1/n} $

However I don't see how to go further without knowing the De Moivre Theorem or Euler's Formula. If it helps, before in this assignment I have shown that $ z \in S^1$
, $\bar z = z^{-1}$ and that the set of n-th roots of unity is a subgroup of $S^1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need De Moivre's theorem, just the geometric view of multiplication of complex numbers. $(re^{i\theta})^n = r^ne^{in\theta}$. You should be able to find $n$ numbers whose $n$th power is $1\cdot e^{i(0)}$.

Comment: Geometric view of multiplication reminds me of the product of the values and the sum of the arguments. - I am not allowed use your equation in this class (yet).

Comment: @kitkat4.4 You don't need that equation; you only need the properties you mentioned.

Comment: Where and how? I only have the trigonometric polar form.

Comment: Don't mess with sine and cosine. Just think about what the modulus and the argument would have to be so that $n$ times complex multiplication would yield 1. Find $n$ numbers such that that is true, and you are good. Can you think of one number such that $z^n=1$? Two numbers?

Comment: Ah, I have already shown that the modili of all n-th roots is definitely $=1$. So now in order to get $1$ after $n$ times multiplication, the sum of the arguments of all the n-th roots has to be $2\pi$ or $360°$, so that I end up at$ z = 1 + 0i$ again. Good so far?

Comment: @kitkat4.4 Yes, the sum could be $0,2\pi, 4\pi, ...$ any of those.